# Selenium not updating dynamic select

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I have two drop-down lists. The second is empty until a selection is made from the first. However, when the first is selected with selenium using `select.selectByIndex()`  or any of the select methods, the second drop-down is not populated.

```
public class ScraperTwo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/user/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.alboautotrasporto.it/web/portale-albo/imprese-iscritte");




        Select firstDropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("_impreseiscritte_WAR_serviziportalealbo100SNAPSHOTesercizioalbo_provinceList")));
        firstDropDown.selectByIndex(10);

        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                Select innerSelect = new Select(d.findElement(By.id("_impreseiscritte_WAR_serviziportalealbo100SNAPSHOTesercizioalbo_comuniList")));
                return innerSelect.getOptions().size() > 0;
            }
        });

        WebElement secondDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("_impreseiscritte_WAR_serviziportalealbo100SNAPSHOTesercizioalbo_comuniList"));

        List<WebElement> allOptions = secondDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

        for(WebElement option: allOptions) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Value is %s", option.getText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not including as an answer as I could not get it to work consistently... Worked 2 out of 5 timees only...  Try with this code... ChromeOptions chop =  new ChromeOptions(); chop.addArguments("test-type"); chop.addArguments("start-maximized"); chop.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content"); WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chop);          Also I put in a Thread.sleep of 5 secs before I clicked the first dropdown...

Answer (score 0):

I hope the web application your working on is using the onblur for the first select drop down. It is better to focus on the next dropdown for you first select to trigger the javascript in the first. Just try including the below code above the webdriverwait for the second select dropdown.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("_impreseiscritte_WAR_serviziportalealbo100SNAPSHOTesercizioalbo_comuniList"));
new Actions(selenium).moveToElement(element).perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver,90).equals((((JavascriptExecutor) selenium).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")));
```

Good luck !